# Changing Screen Name on the Lockscreen or Sign-In Screen

Tags: windows-10

**Perhaps this edit will help anyone of you who can provide a solution better understand the problem I face.  Here is my edit (as of Thursday 26 Oct 17):**
The problem I having involves something I did when managing the name of my computer.  If you look at the upper right portion of my computer screen, you'll find the small circle with a neutral picture silhouette.  Just to the immediate left of that silhouette is a label I changed to identify my name (which it was originally) to another name I gave my computer.  Why I did this?  Well, I guess I was just experimenting with the field to control this label.  Now, I cannot change the label back to what it was originally.  And I don't know how to do this?  Can you provide me with the answer to this dilemma?

**Below this line is what I originally wrote about this problem:**
This process is confusing!  I am in my account settings under Your Info > My profile.  I was playing around (maybe shouldn't have done so) and wrote: "If this ain't your computer then leave now or I'll send my phantoms after you."  or something similar to that between [First Name] and [Last Name] fields.  When I went to start up my computer, I ran into some problems getting past the sign in screen. I'm trying to reverse what I did, and this has been a problem somewhat to me.

Comment: So, you changed your display name and now you cannot login? Can you explain the issues you're having logging in? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent some more time today on the phone with a Microsoft representative, just about 1 hour.

I originally was hoping this rep would guide me in solving my problem.  However, as it turns out, in my efforts to use my own computer experience and logic in describing the problem to this rep, I managed to educate the rep on how to simply solve this problem.  Imagine that!  Here I was asking for help, and I wound up helping the rep.  The best benefit of the rep was his presence and listening skills of me trying to describe the problem, and my logical attempts to solve it.

Okay, we all have to help each other.  And now I want to help any of you who encountered the same problem I faced.  Hey, my way of giving back to this community.  So pay attention.

The rep originally wanted to do a restoration point.  And if that didn't work then the rep wanted to go into some complex troubleshooting.

My response was that it shouldn't be so complicated.  I felt that if I was able to make the original changes then I should be able to do it again.  Simple as that!  But the question was: How to do it?

I discovered their are two ways to do this.  It was just confusing to me to figure out how to get back to the page that allowed me to make the changes I made in the first place.  Okay, I was experimenting originally.  But sometimes that's the only way to figure things out with these computer devices.  Surely, you all have done similar things too.

So, now I will tell you how to get to the window that controls the answer to this situation.  There are two ways to get there depending on where you are starting from.

If you are starting from an open Internet Explorer Window tab then do this:
1. To the left of your silhouette picture you'll see the label describing the picture.  That's where it originally had my first and last name.
2. Right click that label > Left click "Open in new tab"
That will open a new tab.
3. Left click the new tab.  This bring up a window titled: "Email & app accounts" in a Settings Window.
4. Under the link named: "Add a Microsoft account" you'll see the Windows logo to the left of your named main email account.
5. Left click on your main named email account described at #4.  That will expand the name of your email account.  And you will see a button called "Manage".
6. Left click on "Manage".
7. Walla!  You are now taken to a new tab.  That is your Microsoft Account window.  Under the silhouette of a picture circle, you'll see a link called: "Edit Name"
8. Left click "Edit Name" and it takes you to: Your Info.  It is here you will see the fields for "First Name" and "Last Name".
Note: By the way, it is here that I started experimenting with changing the first and last name fields that I described in the original problem statement.

Okay now there's another way to get to the Your Info window.  Perhaps this method is even easier than what I just described above.
1. Starting from your desktop with no open programs of Internet Explorer (IE) tabs.
Note: For this writing, however, I am keeping this window open.  But I have minimized the IE window.
2. Left click the Windows logo at the lower left of your screen.  That expands what I think is called the Windows start screen.
3. Look at the very left of this expanded screen.  In the vertical left most column, you'll see some small icons.
4. On my screen there are 4 possible small icons: a)The Silhouette icon; b) The File Explorer icon; c) The Setting icon, and d) The Power icon.
5. Left click on the Silhouette icon.  Note: By the way, if you hover your mouse over the Silhouette icon then you'll see the name of the Silhouette; which now after I've made my correction is my real name, not the name I was experimenting earlier with.
6. Left click on: "Change account settings".  This opens up a Settings window for Your Info about your account.  (Gosh, writing all this out really takes an effort.  I hope you appreciate it.  And I hope I'm doing a good job.)
7. Look for the link called: "Manage my Microsoft account" and Left click on it.  That will open up a new tab in IE.  That is your account page. (The same one described in the earlier procedure for getting there.)
8. Left click "Edit Name" and it takes you to: Your Info.  It is here you will see the fields for "First Name" and "Last Name".
Note: By the way, it is here that I started experimenting with changing the first and last name fields that I described in the original problem statement.

I just realized either of the above two procedures involves the same amount of steps to get there.  Oh well, I guess that's the way it goes.  At least, you've got two ways to get there.  Thanks Microsoft.

I hope the reader of this post knows the two different ways of getting to the your account info page can confuse the end user.  Why?  Because the end user may have originally forgotten the way they got there in the first place.  And if they're trying to replicate their actions then the two different ways I've described above may show different screens in the process of getting there.  Hence, the end user may just be confused about things because they don't recall the method they first used.  And since both methods just described show different things.  That cause the confusion.  [I really hope Microsoft reads this entire post.  Because they my just see this feedback as a learning experience.  Which hopefully may help Microsoft improve things somehow.]

Okay reader, I hope you're enjoying my efforts here.  Please continue.

So now we are at the Microsoft Account page.
Look for the link: "Edit name" and Left click on it.
Now you'll see the "First name" and "Last name" fields.
Make your changes in those two fields and Left click on Save.
THAT SHOULD SOLVE THIS PROBLEM.

However, I do believe you also need to restart your computer.

Now the above procedures has helped me change the name on my sign in or lock screen upon computer start up.  But there is still a problem in a new tab window of my IE.  The old experimental label that I was trying to remove still appears left of the silhouette picture.  Humm, I still have to figure out why this is so.  Maybe this is a bug in the Microsoft program.  I don't know.

Gee, I just closed out the post and closed and reopened the Internet Explorer and the name to the left of the silhouette picture shows my real first name.  So maybe, just maybe, I've completely solved this problem  Only time will tell.

I hope what I have edited and explained above has helped those of you who have been reading through this post about this problem.

Comment: Yup! My efforts explained above worked.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try boot repair using system built-in repair tool. Also, you can try to boot from installation medium, then, open CMD to run “sfc /scannow”, or, Bootrec.exe to troubleshooting startup problem.

Detail steps referent below.

Windows 10 Won’t Boot? Fix it with Startup Repair and BootRec Commands:
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-windows-10-wont-boot-startup-repair-bootrec/

Use Bootrec.exe in the Windows RE to troubleshoot startup issues:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues